# Issue with Spring application, basend on spring.io tutorial

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, gradle

I'm trying to learn Spring framework so I decided to follow tutorials available on `Spring.io` website. I have an issue in my application with the chapter: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I did it with friend day before and app worked and is still working. I tried to do it on my own and in main class I receive error:

**Error Stack Trace**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The type org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    The method run(Object, String...) from the type SpringApplication refers to the missing type ConfigurableApplicationContext
```

I'm trying to do it at my company office right now, can security software in my company's broadband be at fault?

Main class: **Application.java**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

Comment: did you create it as a maven project ?

Comment: No, I'm using gradle, so i created is as Gradle project

Comment: can you share your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: I found solution, thanks for help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem by simply right-clicking on my build.gradle file and going into gradle tab, then select refresh. It was fault of compiler, similar issue when people used to develop Android apps on that IDE. Sometimes you have to manually refresh it.

Comment: glad to here that you resolved your issue, i was saying same thing to do - resolve the dependency means eliminate compilation error that's it.!! Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to your class path, which do not have required class files. I suggest you to build project stand alone without any ide to check all dependencies resolution and make sure works fine. For that simply set `JAVA_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` (assuming you are using build tool is `MAVEN`)on the environment variable and build your project without any ide (Netbeans or Eclipse) with command (`mvn clean compile package install`) and it will resolve all your dependencies related problem and download required jars from central repository and on successful build jar will be created in target directory of your project.

And if you are using any IDE then make sure all dependencies are available on the class path.

In your case required jar is `spring-boot-starter-web` to resolve issue of `ConfigurableApplicationContext`.

Comment: I'm using Gradle and mentioned jar is called in dependenceis of build.gradle file. But I will try what you said and give an update on situation

Comment: @BartekNowak i am looking forward for that

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I found solution and it was fault of compiler